# Opening mail without any risk

Tags: email, virus

Before opening unknown email (not in spam folder) how we can identify no any danger inside the mail (with availability of active virus guard)

Comment: Could you narrow down the question ? It's unclear what risk, exactly, you want to protect yourself from (malware ? information leaks ? tracking ? Phishing ?)

Answer (score 1):

To be safe from having mails that possibly harm your system through an attack you first need to know what attacks you want to be protected against.

- Mail body Attacks (like malicious HTML inside the mail) Protection options are

  - Open Mail in plain text mode, in this mode None of the text is treated as having special meaning and is just show on the screen, in case of an HTML document you do need to be able to read HTML to understand your mails.
  - Set the mail client to NOT display Images. Images have been used as a means of infecting a system through several means. some involve maliciously crafted images that exploit the viewing system, some that employ Track and Trace for scouting new locations to attack.
  - Disable JavaScript. Some people think that disabling the JavaScript inside mails can protect you. while it does offer a slight barrier in my opinion, I do believe not running any of the code is better. so reading HTML ;)
- Attachments Attacks (Like malicious Zip files) Protection options are

  - Disable Attachments inside the mail server. Hardly a user friendly option.
  - Have a virus scanner integrated into the mail server. solves known viruses but does not protect against directed attacks or new virus (types)
  - Simple NEVER EVER open an attachment unless you specifically asked to be mailed one. (good policy in my opinion.) Mails are most often the most effective when there short and to the point. you do not need to send a big blob of data to do that (like a document)
  - Save attachments and run the virus scanner over them before you view them. same protection as doing this server side with the added bonus of someone consciously doing the task and understanding that there are risks.

In short none of these methods offer a foolproof method of protection or are complete in any way. just use common sense and understanding of how the "bad guys" work go a long way.